# Equivalent of penalty.factor in caret?

Tags: r, r-caret, lasso-regression

I would like to set the penalty of some coefficients to 0 while using Lasso. The glmnet function has an option called penalty.factor for this purpose. Is there an equivalent in the caret package?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the *train* function:

```
model_fit <- train(Data[,-1], Data[,1],method = "glmnet",penalty.factor=rep(1,50),...)
```